# What happens if you buy a Team Specific Ticket for a team that doesn't qualify for the World Cup?

Tags: world-cup, fifa

As an example, you can currently get cheap tickets for the North Macedonia matches in the 2022 World Cup:

[image]

What happens if North Macedonia doesn't qualify? Would you get a refund? Would you get alternative tickets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIFA have set up an FAQs portal here: https://fifa.powerappsportals.com/en-US/qatar2022/

Under the Ticket Products section, it explains that TST tickets for teams that fail to qualify will be subject to a refund of the cost of tickets, minus an administrative charge.

> **11. I have bought a Team Specific Ticket Series. What happens if my chosen national team does not qualify for the FIFA World Cup Qatar 2022™?**
>
> If your chosen national team does not qualify for the FIFA World Cup Qatar 2022™, FIFA Ticketing will refund your payment for your Team Specific Ticket Series, less an administration fee of QAR 40.00 (forty Qatari riyal).